# How to apply a style to a DependencyObject in a custom control library

Tags: wpf

I am creating a reusable custom control, based on the TreeView. I have on the custom control created a dependency property for the columns in the control, like this:

```
    public GridViewColumnCollection Columns
    {
        get { return (GridViewColumnCollection)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), typeof(TreeListView), new PropertyMetadata(new GridViewColumnCollection()));
```

This lets me specify a bunch of columns in XAML. The catch is that I need the first column to have a custom cell template. I was going to approach this by deriving a class from GridViewColumn, something like this:

```
public class TreeGridViewColumn : GridViewColumn
{
}
```

and then give it the desired style in the Generic.xaml for the custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TreeGridViewColumn}">
    <Setter Property="CellTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Black" /> <!-- Just for example -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However the style is never applied to instances of TreeGridViewColumn. I know that I probably need to add:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TreeGridViewColumn), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TreeGridViewColumn)));
```

However I cannot do this, as the GridColumn base class is not a FrameworkObject, it is a DependencyObject. How can I apply a style to a descendant of a GridViewColumn defined in a Custom Control library?

Comment: You can't in any way apply a Style to a GridViewColumn, because it's not a FrameworkElement and therefore not stylable. It has no Style property.

Comment: @Clemens : Correct. I think I could have done a better job explaining this when I wrote the question - I am trying to create a derivative of GridViewColumn with an overridden CellTemplate specific to my needs. I've spent some time using Reflector to look at how the DataGrid columns do this (i.e. Text column, etc) and it looks like unfortunately they just create the default templates manually in code. Which is fine for them because their templates are only one or two framework elements. My template will be far too complex for that to be practical, so I'm going to need to find another route.

Answer (score 1):

Think like this: The TreeGridViewColumn should be a dummy object holding important information for the column itself such as width and height and also for each cell under that columns header for example the cell template itself. Therefore do not try to create an FrameworkElement out of TreeGridViewColumn. Here is an example how you might end up using the TreeGridViewColumn.

```
        <TreeGridViewColumn Header="First Col" Width="50">
            <TreeGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        click me
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </TreeGridViewColumn>
```

Once you ready to display the columns and cells I suggest to you to write your own custom panel which deals with the FrameworkElements by calling their Measure and Arrange methods allowing you to position columns and cells the way you want. You will end up doing alot of math inside your custom panel class. That futhermore means you will end up spending a month on programming that TreeGridView. I suggest you to take a shortcut and download the code of such a thing. There are already few TreeListViews online. Just take their dlls and see if it will work out for you

EDIT:

Ok here is a suggestion how you could solve your issue. Its just a suggestion

The DefaultTextColumnData class is a dummy object holding all the necessary infos like columns width, etc.

DataGridCellControl will be that FrameworkElement that draws the cell. Its a FrameworkElement so it will have a defined style in your generic.xaml resource dictionary.

To sum up DefaultTextColumnData will hold all infos for the column itself. DataGridCellControl will be a control which might end up having 20 instances of itself in case you have 20 cells in that column.

DataGridCellControl must know about its column.
This is how the code of DataGridCellControl will look alike:

```
class DefaultTextColumnData : DataGridColumn
{
}

class ComplexColumnData : DataGridColumn
{
}

class DataGridCellControl : Control
{
  public DataGridColumn Column
  {
    get; set;
  }

  public DataTemplate DefaultTextCellTemplate
  {
    get; set;
  }

  public override Size MeasureOverride(Size size)
  {
   ...
   if(this.Column is DefaultTextColumnData)
   {
    this.Template = this.DefaultTextCellTemplate
   }

   if(this.Column is ComplexColumnData)
   {
    this.Template = ...
   }
   ...
   return new Size(30, 30);
  }
}
```

DefaultTextCellTemplate will be set in your generic.xaml like this:

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type DataGridCellControl}>
 <Setter Property="DefaultTextCellTemplate">
  <Setter.Value>
   <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Background="Black" Margin="5"/>
     ....
```

Thats how you set default cell template in your resource dictionary.

Comment: Thanks but this part I already know and have working. If you check out my other commend on the question - the real problem is that I have one of these columns that I wanted to specialize and have a pre-assigned cell template. Similar to how the DataGrid has a range of pre-configured columns for i.e. text, checkboxes, dropdowns, etc.

Comment: thats what cell template is for

Comment: Copy from above because I can't be bothered rewriting exactly the same thing: " I am trying to create a derivative of GridViewColumn with an overridden CellTemplate specific to my needs. I've spent some time using Reflector to look at how the DataGrid columns do this (i.e. Text column, etc) and it looks like unfortunately they just create the default templates manually in code. Which is fine for them because their templates are only one or two framework elements. My template will be far too complex for that to be practical, so I'm going to need to find another route."

Comment: just use the celltemplate property as it is in xaml.. in your resource dictionary for exapmle.. they are derivating from control class means its a frameworkelement.. hence why you allowed to set any ui element inside cell template in xaml :)

Comment: Either I am not getting it, or you aren't explaining your point very well (or both!). Here's some important points from my question & comments: "I am creating a reusable custom control" (Emphasis on reusable). "overridden CellTemplate specific to my needs" - ok, perhaps this quote was unclear - it needs to be overridden in the custom control library. I thought from context, i.e. "pre-configured columns for i.e. text" that it was clear, but apparently not. So, if you know some way of setting CellTemplate in resources in custom control for a certain type of column then that would be an answer.

Comment: its hard to talk about all those things without code.. but i wrote you an suggestion how you might want to solve your issue. take a look at my edit in my answer